# Cannot add user on Centos Server - Input/Output error

Tags: useradd

Today, on my Centos server I tried to add a user but got the following error:

```
-bash: /usr/sbin/useradd: Input/output error
```

How do i fix it?

Thanks

UPDATE:

var/log/messages is blank

df -h also gives me a the same input/output error:

```
-bash: /usr/sbin/df: Input/output error
```

'free' also gives me the same error:

```
-bash: /usr/sbin/free: Input/output error
```

Also, I cannot even shutdown the server ie: shutdown -s, gives me the same error.

Any ideas what might be the issue?

Comment: More info please.

Anything in `/var/log/messages`?

What does `df -h` say?

What does `mount` say?

Comment: I've run into this once or twice when running out of memory and swap space, there's no room to store stdin/out or write to the terminal buffer sessions I believe.

Comment: So please also show the output of `free`.

Comment: please see my update

Comment: It looks like serious filesystem corruption.  Do you see anything in the output of `dmesg`? Hope you've got backups!

Comment: No I do not have backups. I would like to know, how do you back up a linux server - What commands?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry to agree with Larsks, but FS Corruption seems the most likely culprit. I've seen this a couple of times, and its been disk corruption each time.

If you are able:

```
touch forcefsck
then to reboot, either
init 6
```

OR

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/kernel/sysrq
```

Although avoid the "echo..." because its more akin to hitting the reset button!
Good luck

Comment: Thank you GeoSword, but I contacted my ISP to restart the server from their end since I could not restart it remotely...After the restart, the server is fine now again. But thanks for the tip...